# show that $\frac{1}{2}\le\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k} - \ln(n)\le \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that for all  $n \in \Bbb N,n \ge 1$

$\frac{1}{2}\le\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}  - \ln(n)\le \frac{3}{2}$

I have no idea how to do this...can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: $\ln n$ is area under $1/x$ from $1$ to $n$ you can directly compare the area with harmonic number.

Answer (score 0):

We use the usual name
$$  H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}. $$

We write $\log t = \log_e t,$ where $e = 2.71828...$

You need to be able to estimate $\log (1+t)$ for small real number $t.$ Using that, you can prove that
$$ H_n - \log n  $$
starts large ($1,$) and decreases (each time we add $1$ to $n$), while
 $$ H_n - \log (1+n)  $$
starts small ($1 - \log 2$) but increases. Naturally, we always have
 $$ H_n - \log (1+n) < H_n - \log n. $$

There is more to it, though. For any pair of integers $m,n,$ 
we always have
 $$ H_m - \log (1+m) < H_n - \log n. $$
Probably worth proving this..if $m = n,$ we have it. If $m < n,$ then
 $$ H_m - \log (1+m) < H_n - \log (1+n) < H_n - \log n.  $$ If $m > n,$ then
 $$ H_m - \log (1+m) <  H_m - \log m < H_n - \log n. $$

Indeed, both sequences have, of course, the same limit, called $\gamma,$ each $H_m - \log (1+m) < \gamma,$ while each $\gamma < H_n - \log n.$

```
    n         H_n                     H_n - log(1+n)             H_n - log(n)
    1                        1       0.3068528194400547                        1
    2                      1.5       0.4013877113318903       0.8068528194400547
    3        1.833333333333333       0.4470389722134426       0.7347210446652236
    4        2.083333333333333       0.4738954208992326       0.6970389722134425
    5        2.283333333333333       0.4915738641052782       0.6738954208992328
    6                     2.45       0.5040898509446864       0.6582405307719448
    7        2.592857142857143       0.5134156011773066       0.6469469938018292
    8        2.717857142857143       0.5206325655209232       0.6384156011773066
    9        2.828968253968254        0.526383160974208       0.6317436766320343
   10        2.928968253968254       0.5310729811698832       0.6263831609742081
   11        3.019877344877345       0.5349706950893443        0.621982072078974
   12        3.103210678210678       0.5382613207491413       0.6183040284226777
   13        3.180133755133755       0.5410764255184966       0.6151843976722184
   14        3.251562326562327       0.5435121254601167       0.6125049969470682
   15        3.318228993228994       0.5456402709892124       0.6101787921267836
   16        3.380728993228994       0.5475156491727776       0.6081402709892124
   17        3.439552522640758       0.5491807647445934       0.6063391785845421
   18        3.495108078196314        0.550669099029873       0.6047363203001488
   19        3.547739657143682       0.5520073835896911       0.6033006779772416
   20        3.597739657143682       0.5532172194202589        0.602007383589691
   21        3.645358704762729       0.5543162514044135       0.6008362670393064
   22        3.690813250217275       0.5553190342881251        0.599770796858959
   23         3.73429151108684       0.5562376807388946       0.5987972951576905
   24        3.775958177753507       0.5570823528853059       0.5979043474055611
   25        3.815958177753507       0.5578616397320247        0.597082352885306
    n         H_n                     H_n - log(1+n)             H_n - log(n)
```

Not needed for this question, but
$$ \gamma \approx 0.5772156649  $$